# I want the error message to print after I input the two lists

Tags: python, exception, nameerror

```
try:

    list_one = eval(input())
    list_two = eval(input())

    sum = 0
    newlis = []

    for i in range(len(list_one)):
        newlis.append(list_one[i] * list_two[i])

    for i in newlis:
        sum += i

    print(sum)

except IndexError:
    print("Index out of bound")

except NameError:
    print("The list has some non number values")
```

If I run this code, it asks to enter two lists one by one. I've put an exception in case any list with any non-integer-element is input. Now if I input this list `[1,b,2,4]` on the first time, the error immediately shows up. I want this error message after I input both the lists.

Comment: Then `try..except` only that one `input` statement, store the error in a variable, and later, if an error occurred, output the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make the following :

```py
try:

    list_one, list_two = input(), input()
    list_one, list_two = eval(list_one), eval(list_two)

    sum = 0
    newlis = []

    for i in range(len(list_one)):
        newlis.append(list_one[i] * list_two[i])

    for i in newlis:
        sum += i

    print(sum)

except IndexError:
    print("Index out of bound")

except NameError:
    print("The list has some non number values")
```

But keep in mind that this doesn't prevent passing anything other than numbers, it just prevents passing an element containing a syntax error (like you did in the exemple, as `a` isn't valid, but `"a"` is).

So you will have to add an `except` for `TypeError`, and change the message for your `NameError` :

```py
try:

    list_one, list_two = input(), input()
    list_one, list_two = eval(list_one), eval(list_two)

    sum = 0
    newlis = []

    for i in range(len(list_one)):
        newlis.append(list_one[i] * list_two[i])

    for i in newlis:
        sum += i

    print(sum)

except IndexError:
    print("Index out of bound")

except NameError:
    print("The given object is invalid")

except TypeError:
    print("The object passed isn't a list of numbers")
```